All composite numbers are crossed by the lines
I'm trying a version of the code with the concavity of the parabola upwards (y=x^2), but I'm not succeeding. I appreciate any help.
Manipulate[
 With[{np = NextPrime[xf]}, 
  Plot[{Sqrt[x], -Sqrt[x]}, {x, 0, xf}, Axes -> {False, True}, 
   Epilog -> {Opacity[.4], Purple, 
     Line /@ Flatten[
       Outer[List, Table[{n^2, n}, {n, 2, np}], 
        Table[{n^2, -n}, {n, 2, np}], 1], 1], 
     Opacity[1], {Black, 
      Text[#, {#, 0}] & /@ 
       Complement[Range[np], Table[Prime[n], {n, np}]]}, Red, 
     PointSize[.01], 
     Table[Tooltip[Point@{Prime[n], 0}, Prime[n]], {n, np}], 
     Table[Tooltip[Point@{n^2, n}, n], {n, 2, np}], 
     Table[Tooltip[Point@{n^2, -n}, n], {n, 2, np}]}, 
   ImageSize -> 600]],
 {{xf, 9, "x"}, 4, 50, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]


Could you clarify what your issue is, The code works. However, the visualization of composite numbers with multiple factors means more and more lines will intersect with composites on x-axis.

I made some adjustments to the coordinates.
Manipulate[With[{np = NextPrime[xf]}, Plot[{x^2}, {x, -10, xf}, Axes -> {True, True},
   Epilog -> { Opacity[0.4], Purple, Line /@ Flatten[ Outer[List, Table[{n, n^2}, {n, 2, np}], Table[{-n, n^2}, {n, 2, np}], 1], 1], Opacity[1], {Black, Text[#, {#, 0}] & /@ 
   Complement[Range[np], Table[Prime[n], {n, np}]]},
         Red, PointSize[0.01],
         Table[Tooltip[Point@{Prime[n], 0}, Prime[n]], {n, np}],
         Table[Tooltip[Point@{n, n^2}, n], {n, 2, np}],
         Table[Tooltip[Point@{-n, n^2}, n], {n, 2, np}]
       },
     ImageSize -> 600
   ]
],
{{xf, 9, "x"}, 4, 50, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]


Not sure this is what you are after, but you can just rotate the graph:
Manipulate[
With[{np = NextPrime[xf]}, 
Rotate[Plot[{Sqrt[x], -Sqrt[x]}, {x, 0, xf}, Axes -> {False, True}, 
Epilog -> {Opacity[.4], Purple, 
  Line /@ Flatten[
    Outer[List, Table[{n^2, n}, {n, 2, np}], 
     Table[{n^2, -n}, {n, 2, np}], 1], 1], 
  Opacity[1], {Black, 
   Text[#, {#, 0}] & /@ 
    Complement[Range[np], Table[Prime[n], {n, np}]]}, Red, 
  PointSize[.01], 
  Table[Tooltip[Point@{Prime[n], 0}, Prime[n]], {n, np}], 
  Table[Tooltip[Point@{n^2, n}, n], {n, 2, np}], 
  Table[Tooltip[Point@{n^2, -n}, n], {n, 2, np}]}, 
ImageSize -> 600], 90  Degree]], {{xf, 9, "x"}, 4, 50, 
Appearance -> "Labeled"}]


I appreciate your attention, but just rotating doesn't solve it. The values on the horizontal axis will be inverted, the numbers will be upside down. What I wanted was the same procedure as in the parabola y=x^2. That is, I don't want to analyze the situation with the concavity to the right, but with the concavity upwards.

It looks like you are trying to visualize a plot involving the square root function and points on a parabola. The Manipulate function in Mathematica can be used to create dynamic plots. I'll provide a version that corrects and refines your code for plotting points and lines associated with the parabola y=x^2,I just corrected and refined version of your code it may work as you want:
Manipulate[
  With[{np = NextPrime[xf]},
    Plot[{Sqrt[x], -Sqrt[x]}, {x, 0, xf},
      Axes -> {False, True},
      Epilog -> {
        Opacity[0.4], Purple,
        Line /@ Flatten[
          Outer[List, Table[{n^2, n}, {n, 2, np}],
            Table[{n^2, -n}, {n, 2, np}], 1], 1],
        Opacity[1], {Black,
          Text[#, {#, 0}] & /@ Complement[Range[np], Table[Prime[n], {n, np}]]},
        Red, PointSize[0.01],
        Table[Tooltip[Point@{Prime[n], 0}, Prime[n]], {n, np}],
        Table[Tooltip[Point@{n^2, n}, n], {n, 2, np}],
        Table[Tooltip[Point@{n^2, -n}, n], {n, 2, np}]
      },
      ImageSize -> 600
    ]
  ],
  {{xf, 9, "x"}, 4, 50, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
]


